# Coloring specific parts of a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

```
private JPanel buildCenterPanel(ActionHandler handler)
{
    JLabel[] tiles = {new JLabel("1"),new JLabel("2"), new JLabel("3"), new JLabel("4")}
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    JPanel grid0 = new JPanel();
    JPanel grid1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel grid2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel grid3 = new JPanel();

    JPanel[] panels = {grid0, grid1, grid2, grid3}; 
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
    {
        panels[i].add(tiles[i]);
        if(((JLabel)panels[i].getComponent(0)).getText().equals("2"))
        {
            panels[i].setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        if(((JLabel)panels[i].getComponent(0)).getText().equals("4"))
        {
            panels[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
        centerPanel.add(panels[i]);
    }
    return centerPanel;
```

I want to make a 2 by 2 grid, where the top right corner is red and the bottom right corner is blue, however I get a java file that has the right numbers, but colors that are not in the right place...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This java project goes through multiple classes, so I'm not sure how I should include the tiles array

Comment: 1) mcve should not demonstrate your project, not your problem  2) aren't 2 jpanels enough to demonstrate the problem ?  3) `(JLabel)panels[i]` why do you expect `panels` to hold `JLabels` after you initialized it with `JPanels` ?

Comment: Move them into the MCVE. Note that an MCVE is not your code, merely a short example that displays the same problem. Speaking of which, when I *tried* to make an MCVE of that uncompilable code snippet, [I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLYBe.png). Were you expecting something different? Voting to close for 'no MCVE'.

Comment: Wait... That was what I wanted to get, how did you do that(I'm new and also horrible at code so I don't know what MCVE is)

Comment: ohhh nvm I see, my bad

Comment: I still have no idea on how you managed to produce the result you got... :'(

Comment: *"also horrible at code so I don't know what MCVE is"* Are you also horrible at reading comments intended to help you, and following links? Tip: Add @c0der (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Also I'll try to edit this to make it MCVE but I'm not completely sure how to do that,

Comment: *"I still have no idea on how you managed to produce the result you got."* By making an MCVE. Maybe you'll discover the mistake in your code while making one. If not, post the MCVE and either myself, @c0der, or any of many other people willing to look further into an MCVE will spot the problem.

Comment: *"I'm not completely sure how to do that"* The SSCCE document goes into further detail.

Comment: I hope this is better, to be honest, you can close it, I don't think making a code do the multi color thing is of my caliber

Comment: *"I don't think making a code do the multi color thing is of my caliber"* Then maybe programming is not for you. You also forgot to notify anyone in that comment.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing missing from the method posted is adding the labels to the panel

```
private JPanel buildCenterPanel()
{
    JLabel[] tiles = {new JLabel("1"),new JLabel("2"), new JLabel("3"), new JLabel("4")};
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    JPanel grid0 = new JPanel();
    grid0.add(tiles[0]); // add the label to the JPanel
    JPanel grid1 = new JPanel();
    grid1.add(tiles[1]);
    JPanel grid2 = new JPanel();
    grid2.add(tiles[2]);
    JPanel grid3 = new JPanel();
    grid3.add(tiles[3]);

    JPanel[] panels = {grid0, grid1, grid2, grid3};
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
    {
        panels[i].add(tiles[i]);
        if(((JLabel)panels[i].getComponent(0)).getText().equals("2"))
        {
            panels[i].setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        if(((JLabel)panels[i].getComponent(0)).getText().equals("4"))
        {
            panels[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
        centerPanel.add(panels[i]);
    }
    return centerPanel;
}
```

Using a loop would make it slightly better:

```
private JPanel buildCenterPanel()
{
    int rows = 2, cols = 2;
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));

    for (int i = 0; i < (rows*cols) ; i++)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //construct a panel
        panel.add(new Label(String.valueOf(i+1))); //add label to it
        //set panel's background 
        if(i == 1) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        }else if(i == 3) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
        centerPanel.add(panel);
    }
    return centerPanel;
}
```

A [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be as simple as :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel{

    private final static int ROWS = 2, COLS = 2;

    public TestPanel() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));

        for (int i = 0; i < (ROWS*COLS) ; i++)
        {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new Label(String.valueOf(i+1)));

            if(i == 1) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.red);
            }else if(i == 3) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
            add(panel);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(new TestPanel());
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
- No but like seriously thanks :)